# My navbar isn't showing on mobile devices

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get my code to work on mobile devices. I want the navbar to show as collapsible tabs, and it's just not showing up that way. I'm not sure if it's because of the custom style or because something is missing or added in the navbar. I added the logo because I wasn't sure if that can be contributing factor to the absense of the navbar. Thanks in advance.

```
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
    <p><a href="index.html">Title Here</a></p>
    </div>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="bio.html">Bio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="lessons.html">Lessons</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="shows.html">Shows</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="music.html">Music</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
<pre> and this is the customstyle.css</pre>
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
    position:absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    left:33%;
    margin-top: 7%;
    }

    .navbar li a {
    color:#000000;
    font-size: 15px;
    }
    .navbar li a:focus, .navbar li a:hover{
    -webkit-transition:1s;
    }
    .logo{
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left:40%;
    font-size: 20px;

    font: 80px "munich", Sans-serf, Ariel;
    margin: 20px;
    }

    .logo a:focus, .logo a:hover{
     -webkit-transition:1s;
     color:#999999;
     text-decoration: none;
     }
     .logo li a:focus, .logo li a:hover{
     -webkit-transition:1s;
     color:#000000;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is showing it just isen't visible add `navbar-default` class to your nav element.

For the dropdown to work when clicked you also need to include the `bootstrap.js` file which has requires `jquery` i've included it in the example so u can see it in action.

[Example](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/LpmPVr?editors=101)

Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

And i've noticed your logo is outside the nav you need to put it in to show correctly

Like this:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, however, now the text aligns to the right.

Comment: @EricaRodriguez glad it helped :D, i would ask you to assign the question as correct if it helped as it motivates users on stackoverflow to answer promptly.